# Wireguard on Nginx Proxy Manager and VPS - Correct Routing

Tags: vpn, routing, vps, wireguard

At home I have an ISP that gives me CGNAT.

So I have a VPS as wireguard server up and running. On my homelab I've got a VM with Ubuntu and Nginx Proxy Manager installed.
On this VM I also installed wireguard to connect to the VPS.

Topology Picture:

[image: Topology Picture]

In my LAN the NginxProxyManager (NPM) GUI is available over 172.16.0.9:81

The routing works as expected. If i connect to the public VPS over my subdomains I see my webservers. So that works great.
But I have to use "AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0" on the NPM wireguard config. Any other config doesn't work.

As far as I bring up the wireguard tunnel, I can't connect to my NPM via local network at all. But it has internet connection.
It has something to to with the AllowedIPs Config.

I visit https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2021/03/wireguard-allowedips-calculator/
and tried many different configs with disallowing local address ranges etc.... But nothing works.
Either i can reach my webservers through public IP of VPS or I can reach my NPM locally, but not simultaneous.

Here are my configs so far:

VPS config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ****
ListenPort = 51999
Address = 192.168.200.1/24

PostUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ens192 '!' --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.200.2
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens192 -j SNAT --to-source z.z.z.z
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i ens192 '!' --dport 51999 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.200.2
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o ens192 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT

PostDown = iptables -t nat -F
PostDown = iptables -F FORWARD;

[Peer]
PublicKey = *****
AllowedIPs = 192.168.200.2/32
```

NPM config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ****
Address = 192.168.200.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = ****
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = z.z.z.z:51999
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

---

**EDIT:**
On NPM wireguard, before i bring up the tunnel i got:

ip route:

```
default via 172.16.0.1 dev ens18 proto static
172.16.0.0/24 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.9
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-00d63081655a proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
```

ip rule:

```
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

after bringing up the tunnel:

ip route:

```
default via 172.16.0.1 dev ens18 proto static
172.16.0.0/24 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.9
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-00d63081655a proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
192.168.200.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.200.2
```

ip rule:

```
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Comment: Ah, so NPM is running "inside" and not on the VPS. In that case search for earlier threads that mention 'policy routing' and `ip rule`.

Comment: I did, but i don't get it... I edited my original post to show ip rule and ip route.

So when i bring up the tunnel I can ping 1.1.1.1 as well as the tunnel is routing like I want (everything is routed from public IP of VPS to the webservers behind NPM keeping the original source IP).

So everything like I want, except the fact, that local incomming connections to NPM via it's local IP 172.16.0.9 are not working. But the default rules are still existing and are on the top of the rules. So I don't understand why it's blocking incoming traffic via ens18

Comment: How do you know it's blocking incoming traffic and not outgoing? It could very well be that it's receiving the packets but can't send replies back to you.

Comment: Thats a point. But doesn't I just need to add rules like this?:

`ip rule add prio 32000 from 172.16.0.0/16 lookup main`

`ip rule add prio 32001 from 172.16.0.0/16 lookup default`

`ip rule add prio 32002 from 10.0.0.0/8 lookup main`

`ip rule add prio 32003 from 10.0.0.0/8 lookup default`


where 10.x.x.x. is my local net and 172.16.x.x/16 is DMZ
Shouldn't it then use the main or default routing, wwhich is using the ens18 for default?
I tried the above rules, but that doesnt't work.

Comment: Do you actually have anything in the `default` table? It feels like you're confusing routes and rules; the _default route_ is not the same as the _routing table_ named 'default'. Your original default route is in the table called `main`. (And it seems like wg-quick puts its default route in the unnamed table 51820 as your output shows?) Take a look at `ip route ls table default` and `ip route ls table 51820`, what do they both show?

Comment: Yeah I am having a hard time 'cause I am pretty new to routing/wireguard at all.

table default in fact doesn't exists.
`ip route ls table 51820` shows `default dev wg0 scope link`.

A tcpdump shows that incoming traffic arrives as u mentioned. But the outgoing traffic doesn't seem to arrive the client

Comment: Right, I don't fully remember wg-quick's behavior, what happens if you specify e.g. `Table = 1234` in your wg-quick profile? Does it still add any rules in `ip rule`?

Comment: No. When i specify `Table = Off` or somthing else like `Table = 1234` no rules are added. Then I can connect locally to NPM but there is no more routing from (or to) VPS

Comment: Okay, then continue using `Table = 1234` (any number, but not 'off') and manually add the policy rules you need – that is, any traffic that needs to go via WireGuard has `lookup 1234`. (iptables fwmarks could be useful here, but `from <net>` will probably work well enough. Do you ever need to reach 192.168.200.2 from DMZ or will it always be 172.16.0.9?)

Comment: Hmm, so i specified `Table = 1234`. After I bring up the tunnel I can connect to 172.16.0.9 from local network. Then I added `ip rule add not from 10.0.0.0/8 lookup 1234`. My thought was, that everything is going through the tunnel excpet connections to/from 10.x.x.x (what is my PC's IP-Address). But neither connection from "outside" is possible nor connection through local network after adding this rule. I also added `ip rule add not from 172.16.0.0/16 lookup 1234` with the thought that my local router must be reachable for NPM. But that didn't work at all.

Comment: Don't forget to exclude WireGuard's own traffic from the tunnel... I'd suggest trying a more scoped `from 192.168.200.2 lookup 1234` first, to only include traffic from the tunnel host (mainly, the return traffic from NPM).

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is a route for `10.0.0.0/8` (via `172.16.0.1`, I suppose) in the `main` table. (Then you don't need to mess with `Table=` or `ip rule`.)

Comment: @TomYan: That would be on the other end of the tunnel – this is, as I understand, being configured on the NPM host, which needs to reply to connections from various WAN hosts over the tunnel.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes and no. From what I understand, "the other WAN" is limited to the OP's "non-DMZ local network" (probably another VLAN at home?), which he doesn't want/need it to be accessible from the VPS end. (But it's true that my suggestion my lead to conflict if he needs the NPM to be accessible from "another" `10.0.0.0/8`, or a subset.)

Comment: @TomYan: Well, look at the diagram – the VPS with its public IP is where the inbound connections start. The VPS needs a route only to the NPM (which is just the tunnel's own subnet – probably not even to the DMZ, as NPM will proxy), but the NPM host needs a route back to the entire Internet.

Comment: @u1686_grawity yes, that's why he needs `AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0` on the NPM host. The problem is, when he uses that, the `suppress_prefixlength 0` trick used by wg-quick does not cover his "local network", because apparently he is not referring to `172.16.0.0/24`, but `10.0.0.0/8` (or actually, a subset), which relies on the default route in the `main` table to work, which is in turn "overriden" when he brings up the wg with `AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0`. (The "local network" has not been included in his diagram.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820
32766:  from all lookup main
```

First of all you need to understand the meaning of the ip rules here, especially the first one. When you use `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0`, wg-quick doesn't exactly make your system route all non-WG-encapsulated traffics out of the wg interface. The top rule here effectively means that all routes except the `default` route in your `main` table will still be used, since it is the only route that has prefix length equal to or less than `0`. (`default` is basically an alias of `0.0.0.0/0`.)

Usually a host would have specific routes, namely the "prefix routes", for its "local network(s)". However, in your case, apparently what you mean by "local network" is really a network that is "remote" to the NPM host.

I'm not going to dive deep in how we define whether a network is "local" or "remote" here, and it is not the root cause of the problem here anyway, but it does more or less result in the root cause, i.e., your `main` table does not have specific / non-`default` route that covers this "local network" of concern (namely, `10.0.0.0/8`). The result is, traffics with a destination that belongs to the subnet will be routed into the tunnel instead of to `172.16.0.1` for further forwarding, since the `default` route in the `main` table is effectively overridden by the one in the `51820` table (with the marked WG-encapsulated traffics being the exception).

Therefore, IMHO the simplest solution is to add a specific route for `10.0.0.0/8` to the `main` table (and not mess with `Table=` or `ip rule` yourself). This assume that you don't need to reach the NPM from yet another `10.0.0.0/8` (that is not source NAT'd / IP masqueraded at any point) on the VPS side. (For example, say you have a bunch of VPSes that belong to the same network which makes use of `10.0.0.0/8` or a subset of it.)

FWIW, if this "local network" does not actually have a prefix length of `/8` (but e.g., really just some `/24` with `10` being the first octet), it's better to route more specifically.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me.
I think you got the point. That's exactly what my Setup looks like. I forget to add my VLAN's to the topology. That's right.
So I tried what you said... Deleted the `Table = ` Settings from wg config and set Allowed IPs to `0.0.0.0/0`. After bringing up the tunnel the `main` table looks like: 
`32766:  from all lookup main` and `32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0`. So I tried adding this: `ip rule add from 10.10.60.0/24 table main`. Then it added `32763:  from 10.10.60.0/24 lookup main` to the main table. but still not working. Did I correct?

Comment: Ok NOW I got it. Just needed to add `ip route add 10.10.60.0/24 via 172.16.0.1`

Comment: @cruunnerr Yeah, or if you prefer an ip rule instead, you need a `to 10.10.60.0/24 lookup main` one (with `priority` lower / precedence higher than the `lookup 51820` one, so `PostUp=`).

Comment: Thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys :) I have almost the same setup, but I'm struggling with SNAT on the NPM site. With:

```
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens192 -j SNAT --to-source z.z.z.z
```

The original IP from the client is also forwarding to the NPM server and from there you forward the 80/443 traffic per reserve proxy to other machines.

But if I want to forward specific ports from the NPM server to another local server, with SNAT to remain the original IP from the client, it doesn't work for me. However, with MASQUERADE it work. The problem with MASQUERADE is that on the local machine I only see the IP from the NPM machine, not the original IP from the client:

VPS:

```
Address = 192.168.4.1/24

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

PostUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 1234-j DNAT --to 192.168.4.2
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source z.z.z.z

PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

PostDown = iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 1234-j DNAT --to 192.168.4.2
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source z.z.z.z

AllowedIPs = 192.168.4.2/24
```

NPM

```
Address = 192.168.4.2/24
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.6:1234; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.6:1234; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j MASQUERADE
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

Has maybe someone an idea how I can also forward the original IP form VPS to NPM to a local machine?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).